# I cannot start site created with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I created a site with Symfony with instructions [from this site](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/tutorial/1_2/en/my-first-project).

Last command which I did was:

```
$ php symfony help propel:generate-module
```

I created database in MySQL as is written in instruction. In database I have two tables post and comment.

I have folders:

```
d:\xampp\htdocs\sf_sandbox\apps\frontend\modules\post 
d:\xampp\htdocs\sf_sandbox\apps\frontend\modules\comment
```

But when I try run this site using commend:

```
localhost:8081/sf_sandbox/web/frontend_dev.php/post
```

or

```
localhost:8081/sf_sandbox/web/frontend_dev.php/comment
```

Mozilla is loading the site and nothing do happens, any error is shown, only sign reload current page spins around.

How can I run my first site ?

Comment: If you are starting with Symfony **right now**, you should start [using the last version, ie: the 2.0](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html) instead of 1.x.

Comment: Ok, I stoped apache in xampp and did this comment: php -S localhost:8081 -t d:/xampp/htdocs, server started: D:\xampp\htdocs\sf_sandbox>php -S localhost:8081 -t d:/xampp/htdocs
PHP 5.4.7 Development Server started at Sat Jan 19 15:07:04 2013
Listening on http://localhost:8081
Document root is D:\xampp\htdocs
Press Ctrl-C to quit. But now I cannot starty any site: localhost:8081/index.php, when xampp was started this site displayed correctyl

Comment: When I run server with this command: php ./app/console server:run it works ok, site localhost:8000 display: Welcome!

Congratulations! You have successfully installed a new Symfony application. But I don't know how to run sf_sandbox/web/frontend_dev.php/post from this server

Comment: I download Symfony 2.1.7 and is the same

Comment: [hint #1] use Unix system instead of Windows, otherwise you'll struggle with such errors a lot more. Install ubuntu and forget those problems :) [hint #2] Get familiar with XAMPP logs (this is a package including Apache2 HTTP, isn't it?) Read access and error logs. I guess you may have made a mistake with directory path or file permissions. Read logs carefully - it's all there. [hint #3] forget about sf1.x and about propel - use doctrine instead. If you understand doctrine well enough, then you may try to use propel and compare them, but not now.